# No wireless interfaces

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, wireless, raspbian-jessie

The icon in the tray does not show any wireless interfaces when I click on it.  I know my adapter SHOULD work (Tenda W522U), but it does not appear to.  I am running Raspbian Jessie.  The output of commands is listed below.

lsusb

```
...
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:3572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3572 Wireless Adapter
...
```

lsmod

```
...
rt2800usb   17802  0
rt2800lib   71907  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb    8553  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib   36744  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211   542174  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211   420690  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt    1161  1 rt2800lib
rfkill      16659  1 cfg80211
...
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

Comment: try running the command sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

Comment: Still nothing. No output in the terminal, either.

Comment: have you tried to set a static IP? Don't do that yet if you haven't.

Comment: I have before. It worked on Raspbian Wheezy over Ethernet.

Comment: Try rebooting and leave the wireless adapter plugged in. Then try ifconfig wlan0 up without an ethernet plugged in

Comment: No dice. Still showing no interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

I just struggled with the same problem. 
I noticed that if I ran ifconfig wlan0 would show up but I would only have an ipv6 adress, the other one was completely gone.

I read that in the release of Raspian Jessie the way you have to configure wifi changed. Instead of setting up my static ip adress in `/etc/network/interfaces` I put them in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

To configure my static ip I added the following lines at the end of the file.
(Of course you have to replace the stuff with what's applicable to your network settings)

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.xx.x/24
static routers=192.168.xx.x
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 #DNS server of google
```

I read it [here](http://raspberrytips.nl/vast-ip-adres-raspbian-jessie/) (my source is dutch though)

Comment: I was having same problem due to a someone who made a change in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and then did not back the change back out. The result of the entry caused the same error as the OP as I think my PI 3 was looking for a specific SSID rather than the `auto` functionality. I was at a loss until I found this question and answer which told me which file to look at. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you broke it by fiddling with the settings.
See:-
[How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)